# Trying to allow my discord bot to give roles, but nothing happens no error message either

Tags: python, discord.py

```
import discord
@client.event
async def on_message(message): 
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if "Admin" in message.content.lower():
        role = get(message.server.roles, name=('admin'))
    await client.add_role(message.author, role)
```

No matter what I change it always just says that the client has no attribute of adding roles.

Comment: your indentation looks all wrong in this snippet...

Comment: The code is correctly indented in the actual code

Comment: Please read the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you show us your code exactly as you actually have it, since indentation is vital in Python.

Comment: That said: the error message you describe is pretty straightforward. If you want your bot to add roles to other users, then the bot has to have an account *that is allowed to do that*. It seems like you want this bot to be able to make other users into server admins. It will have to be a server admin itself in order to do that. Also, do you *really* want to let anyone who joins the server be an admin, just by using a bot command?

Comment: Well admin was just the first thing that popped in my head for a role to use as a test, if It works then I will obviously change it to be something else. The bot also already has administrator privileges, so there should be no permissions issues.

Comment: `"Admin"` will never be in `message.content.lower()` since `"Admin".lower()` is `"admin"` and `"Admin" != "admin"`

Comment: Yea I noticed that and fixed that part but it isn't letting me edit the post to change it to be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `message.author.add_roles(role)` to add a role to message author.
Also do not use `message.server.roles`. Write `message.guild.roles` instead.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if "admin" in message.content.lower():
        role = get(message.guild.roles, name="admin")
        await message.author.add_roles(role)
```

Comment: Now it just says member object has no attribute add role, which makes no sense because the word member isn't even in my code at all.

Comment: @RishabhNambiar It was a typo. I edited my answer, see it again please.

Comment: @RishabhNambiar You are welcome! Could you accept my answer, please? (if it was helpful)